# How can I give an CW complex structure to the space $X$ using a covering map $p:X\rightarrow E$ where $E$ has structure of CW complex?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, cw-complexes

I think that idea is to take an n-cell $X_{n}$ of space $E$ a proof $p^{-1}(X_{n})$ is a union of n-cells in $X$. I found in other post the idea is right, but I can't prove that, in my case n-cells are open, therefore I can't use compactness argument of cells.
I really appreciate your help.

Comment: I think that you can use the homotopy lifting property one cell at a time. Inductively, the zero cells should present no problem (just take their preimages) Then regard 1-cells as homotopies between them etc.

Comment: Are you allowed to use cellular approximation? At some point, there has to be a somewhat technical proof for why the preimage of an $n$-cell consists of disjoint copies of the $n$-cell, but cellular approximation would do most of the work for you. You have the right idea for sure.

Comment: I take it back; Andres's idea is better and even gives you the characteristic maps all at once.

Comment: Your question is too vague.  I think you do not want to find an arbitrary CW-structure on $X$, but it should have the property that $p$ becomes cellular (or even stronger, maps open cells of $X$ homeomorphically onto open cells of $E$). If so, edit your question.

Comment: @AndresMejia, thanks. Can you explain a little more?, because my problem is to prove  $p^{-1}(X_{n})$ is a union of n-cells using the lifting, because I have a lifting for each point in preimage of a fixed point in E. My idea with your suggestion is to take covering of $X_{n}$ with evenly open sets but i don't know how to continue. THANKS

Comment: @PaulFrost, I think that my question is clear, because I need to build a CW complex structure on space $X$ using a covering map $ p:X \rightarrow E$ and CW complex structure of space $E$

Comment: @RobertoVargas I found a reference using the lifting property in [Bredon's topology & geometry](http://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/~ralph/math215b/Bredon.pdf) section 4 theorem 8.10.